# Hash Param[:id] before_Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route,the value of the id is encrypted,which means it has to be decrypted before the action is called,my question is how do i get the id,decrypt it and set the new one to the route using a before_action filter,below is what i have tried 
controller:

```
before_action :reverse_id, only: :public_download

def reverse_id 
  @swapped_id = params[:id]
  @id = ScatterSwap.reverse_hash(@swapped_id).to_i
  params[:id] = @id

end

def public_download
  //do something
end
```

this is my route

```
get "get_score/:id/", to: "controller_name#public_download", as:       :get_score
```

Comment: Doesn't it work?

Comment: No it doesn't,i get the same id i put into the url rather than the decrypted value

Comment: Interesting, but not surprising. Fortunately for you, you don't have to mutate params at all. Why not simply replace `MyModel.find(params[:id])` with `MyModel.find(decrypt(params[:id]))`? (where decrypt method does only that, decryption)

Comment: thanks.your suggestion worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code doesn't work. I get the same id i put into the url rather than the decrypted value

Fortunately for you, you don't have to mutate params at all. Why not simply replace `MyModel.find(params[:id])` with `MyModel.find(decrypt(params[:id]))`? (where `decrypt` method does only that, decryption)